# If HTML "Product A" exists, change it to "Price A" using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, I’ve been trying to workaround an issue here. I’ve got so far and I may not be heading in the right direction so if there’s a better way to approach this then let me know.

I’m using Dynamic Text Replacement on a platform called Unbounce to pull form dropdown data from a form submission on my page and then place it onto a confirmation popup overlay.

What I’d like to do next is replace the dynamic text with something different based on which answer from the form has been placed there (answers are limited to 5 specific selections from a dropdown).

Basically, when someone selects product A from the dropdown in the form they would be shown a price for product A in the confirmation dialog popup (instead of being shown ‘Product A’).

I’ve come across some text replacement javascript that I’ve used and tested successfully on the page.

```
<h3 id="title"class="lato dark bold title">certain text</h3>
<span class="orange size22"><b id="subtitle" >this text</b></span>

<script>
  if (document.getElementById('title').innerHTML == "certain text" ) {
     document.getElementById('subtitle').innerHTML = 'new text';
  }
</script>
```

My hope was to add an ID to `<ub:clientsidedynamic>` for it to find at least one of my dropdown options such as ‘Product A’ and replace it with my desired price.

I changed the original dynamic text source code with:

```
<ub:clientsidedynamic class="text-editor-dynamic-tag" id="title" contenteditable="true" method="" parameter="window_type" title="URL Parameter: window_type" wrap="true">PRICE</ub:clientsidedynamic>
```

adding the ID of ‘title’ in a hope that it would work with my above Javascript.

Does anybody have any idea as to why this doesn’t work? Or if I’m even heading in a plausible direction with this.

Many thanks.

Comment: So what is the error in the console? Did you debug and see what `document.getElementById('title').innerHTML` is?

Comment: I will try that. It threw this up as an error <ub:clientsidedynamic id="title"> = $1

Comment: Maybe the javascript code ub:clientsidedynamic is loaded after you replace; you may the following, wait 5s before replacing:
`<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
     if (document.getElementById('title').innerHTML == "certain text" ) {
       document.getElementById('subtitle').innerHTML = 'new text';
     }
  }, 5000);
</script>`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.